# Does Acromegaly cause actual expansion of the zygomatic(cheek) bone

Tags: human-biology, bone-biology, growth

Acromegaly is a disorder in adults involving excess growth hormone production. Since epiphyseal fusion has already taken place in most bones of adults , this does not cause an increase in stature. Certain features of the face such as the jaw may be changed due the fact that the flat bones, such as the maxilla do not undergo epiphyseal fusion and may enlarge.

Several reports describe a prominent zygomatic arch due to arcomegaly, such as [this](http://journals.lww.com/annalsplasticsurgery/Abstract/1981/07000/Surgical_Treatment_of_Facial_Deformity_Secondary.11.aspx). As I understand ,the zygomatic bone cannot enlarge due to its being fused in adults.

Can acromegaly cause an actual enlargement of the underlying zygomatic bone ?